# How to simulate directional wind?

Tags: physics, game-physics

I am currently developing hair strand system for my project. Currently I am using verlet integration to simulate gravity and wind.

Wind vector is currently just a vector. But I want to make a more realistic wind.

Is there any papers or articles that I should read about? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how deep you want to go with the simulation. I suppose that you want something more interesting than uniform wind with varying direction and intensity.
I would suggest adding turbulent velocity to each strand with 3D Curl/Simplex noise. Even animated Perlin noise might be cheap and fast enough for your needs, but you might be able to get more dramatic effects with curl noise.

The original paper for curl noise is here: http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~rbridson/docs/bridson-siggraph2007-curlnoise.pdf

You can also find several implementations of it, but the basic idea is still the same - perturbing particles according to an underlying flow-field.